# Convert a binary string into an array of integers in swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I tried to converting a string into an array, but its showing error

```
var boolean = "01101010101001010111"
```

i tried to spilt the string by characters it didn't worked and tried to convert it into array.

```
resultArray = [0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1]
```

My code attempt

```
boolean = "01101010101001010111"
let componentsArray =  boolean.components(separatedBy: .controlCharacters) 

resultArray = Array(componentsArray) as! [Int]
```

And the error

**Error: Generic parameter "Element could not be inferred"**

Comment: What did you try and what error did you get? What result do you expect for the string "0-X/1Y€"?

Comment: updated with error @MartinR

Comment: @Joe `let resultArray = boolean.characters.flatMap{Int(String($0))}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution (now updated for Swift 4 and later):

```
let zeroOneString = "01101010101001010111"

let resultArray = zeroOneString.compactMap { char in
    char == "0" ? 0 : char == "1" ? 1 : nil
}

print(resultArray) // [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

`zeroOneString.compactMap` maps the sequences of all characters in the string.
The closure maps "0" to `0` and "1" to `1`. Everything  else is mapped to `nil` and ignored by `compactMap`.

Comment: Swift 5 Update: 
```let array = str.compactMap { $0 == "0" ? 0 : 1}```